# py2exe issue with wxpython

Tags: wxpython, py2exe

I am trying to generate .exe file from .py file using py2exe.
But I am getting the following error after running the generated .exe file in dist folder.

```
  File "upto_tabs_b.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "wx\__init__.pyc", line 17, in <module>
  ImportError: No module named core
```

I am using wxpython version 3.0. The error resolves when using version 4.0 but I specifically need 3.0. Below is my setup.py file

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(
    console=['upto_tabs_b.py'],
)
```

I searched a lot for the issue and could not find any helpful resources. It would be extremely helpful if anyone can find a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using wxPython for a GUI, then you shouldn’t use “console”, but “windows” as a keyword in your setup.